# Generate Markdown using F-string with padding and formatting (value could be 'None' as well..)

Tags: markdown, padding, f-string

I have variables called "variable" "size" and "unit. The values can be as following:

```
variable = "short name = "
or
variable2 = "extra long long name = "
```

and

```
dimension = 1.2345
or
dimension2 = 6.78
or
dimension3 = None
```

and

```
unit = " mm"
unit2 = None
```

I want to generate a markdown that results in something visually pleasing like this:

```
short name      = 1.23 mm  # 1.2345 shortened to 2 digits on purpose, space after as well)
extra long name = 6.78 
None            = None  # empty line should be shown ...
```

So I tried the following. But this has no padding, no formatting of the number etc.

```
markdown_string = (
      f"{variable} {dimension} {unit} \n"
      f"{variable} {dimension} {unit} \n"
      f"{variable} {dimension} {unit} \n"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the tricky part, which is the `dimension` (could be a float or `None`).

First, for a float we would do this: `f{dimension:>4.2f}`. This ensures all decimal points line up by right aligning (`>`), sets total length to `4`, sets decimal points with `.2` and defines the float format with `f`.

But for the `None`, that won't work. In fact, there is no format options for None types There, we need to convert the None object to an object which does support format options. At it turns out, the only type which will work is `string`: `f'{str(dimension):>4}'`.

Now we need to combine them. First, a complex statement can be used in the `{}` block. Second, the format string needs to be at the end of the `{}` block. And third, a second `{}` block can be used to build the format string. So this will work:

```py
f'{str(dimension) if dimension is None else dimension:>4{"" if dimension is None else ".2f"}}'
```

Let's combine that with the other objects on a line:

```py
f'{variable:<15} {str(dimension) if dimension is None else dimension:>4{"" if dimension is None else ".2f"}} {"" if unit is None else unit} \n'
```

You did not specify whether the `unit` needs to be the same length so I didn't add padding there.

```py
data = (
    ('short name =', 1.2345, 'mm'),
    ('extra long long name =', 6.78, None),
    (None, None, None)
)
markdown_string = ''

for variable, dimension, unit in data:
    markdown_string + f'{variable:<15} {str(dimension) if dimension is None else dimension:>4{"" if dimension is None else ".2f"}} {"" if unit is None else unit} \n'
```